# How to configure my web.config before publishing my web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, publish

I have published my website to my domain name from Visual Studio...

For that I have modified my Web.Config file like this:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=mssql001.hosting.combell.com;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User Id=MyUserId;Password=MyPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="TennisOnlineContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Tennis.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 " />
```

When I'm trying to navigate it in my Web Browser I get the following error:

***Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MyUserId'.***

I'm using "Combell" business that supports SQL Server 2008... I have contacted the support online and the username and password seem corrects ;)

**Can you tell me what is wrong with my connection string please ?** Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using SQL Server Management Studio  or any sql gui to log in with the same credentials.

Comment: Ok thank you I'm going to log in with SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Bear in mind that in a browser the code will run under the asp.net account. You could modify your site to use either a specific account you set up for the job or to impersonate the caller

Comment: @SimonWilson just a quick note on the connect string - integrated security wasn't specified in the connect string though. Impersonation would be very questionable here as the connect string shows this is a hosted db.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but are remote connections allowed in your SQL Server instance?

Check this page to see how: http://forums.asp.net/t/1338911.aspx/1

or this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Combell sets the name of your database to the same value as your username.